# Sitecore - ECM Module how to map a new Newsletter template branch to the Target Audience template

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms, sitecore-ecm

I have created a new content Email Manager + A Target Audience.
When I select the item "Target Audience", I get 6 options to create a new Newsletter.
I would like to insert a new one, specific for my project.

I have duplicated the branch Newsletter Message and update the content (Layout / Items linked to the root branch ...). Now, I would like to see it to be able to insert / create a new newsletter based on what the project / client needs.

Where is the link ? I cannot find it. I have parsed different item template, but I didn't find where do I have to link the Target audience template with my new Branch Newsletter template.

Any tips / helps with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add it as an Insert Option to the `/sitecore/templates/Branches/Email Campaign/Target Audience Branch/$name/Drafts` item.

You can add an Insert Option with the help of the ribbon in Content Editor: `Configure tab -> Insert Options -> Assign`.

Comment: Indeed, it was working. I solved my issue. I was looking at the Target Audience Template item instead of in the Branch Target Audience Item.